# Can't install Mixpanel iOS SDK via manual install - Mixpanel/Mixpanel.h file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, mixpanel

Following the steps to repro the issue:

1. Cloned the code from https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-iphone
2. Copied the Mixpanel directory to my Xcode project directory
3. Added the Mixpanel directory to Xcode, using the "Create group" and "Copy items if needed" options.
4. Added the frameworks listed in the Podspec file in the Build Phases section of Xcode
5. Added `import "Mixpanel.h"` to my `AppDelegate.m` file
6. Cmd+R
7. Compile error in `Mixpanel+HostWatchOS.h` - `'Mixpanel/Mixpanel.h' file not found`

Also I tried adding `$(SRCROOT)/Mixpanel` to my Libarry Search Paths.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next steps:

1. Go to `Mixpanel+HostWatchOS.h` and rename `#import <Mixpanel/Mixpanel.h>` to `#import "Mixpanel.h"`
2. Then you'll probably face [the next problem](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-iphone/issues/321), so try to do as comment says: add `libicucore.tbd` into your project under `Project/Target/General/Linked Frameworks and Libraries`.
3. Build and Run

But I recommend you to use [CocoaPods' Mixpanel project](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Mixpanel)

Comment: I would love to use pods as well, but it was causing some issues with the Facebook SDK when I tried it... thanks for the solution BraveS!

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure: I work on the iOS SDK at Mixpanel.

Sorry you're having trouble with our manual integration! There was an issue with a recent release that is now corrected on master. You can either `git pull` the latest copy of master, or if you add `$(SRCROOT)/Mixpanel` to your **Framework Search Paths** you should be good to go!

Highly recommend CocoaPods as well, as it makes these things painless. We also support Carthage if you want a one time build of a framework so you don't have to deal with rebuilding pods all the time.

You can also reach out to support@mixpanel.com, they are *great*!

Comment: I tried adding $(SRCROOT)/Mixpanel to my Framework Search Paths and in my AppDelegate.m file I have tried to import: #import "Mixpanel.h" but it still can't find it?  What am I doing wrong?  The Mixpanel folder is in the root of my project? Also just as a note, I think Mixpanel should simply supply the user with a .framework file.   Wouldn't that be much easier?  Seems Tune does this and manual installation was a snap for that...